# How to unlock iphone device before build

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I want to make my developing life easier.

On android devices, there is a setting "never lock if charging"
so whenever the device is hooked up to the development environment, since it is technically charging, the device never shows the lock screen.

On `iphone` the situation is different, I did not find such a setting.

Best i could find was to lock the device after 5 minutes of inactivity, or never(which kills the battery pretty quickly, if i forget to remove that)

is there a script, or a setting, or anything, that i can do to make the `iphone` become unlocked whenever i click "run" from `xcode` ?

Comment: best way is to temporarily disable your passcode in my opinion...This works best if you have dedicated test devices

Comment: if you device is locked with passcode, computer can't do much to it (for good security reason). you can't have a script to enter passcode and unlock the device for you.

Comment: disable the passcode. It works!